# Loading time so slow

Tags: javascript, laravel, nginx

I'm a few hours trying to solve a problem of performance.

**What I did attempting to solve loading time issues > 3s:**

- Enabled GZip compression
- Minify and compressed JS and CSS assets

Everything *works fine on a local environment*, but on production ... **doesn't work!**

- **app.js** has a size of 753kb with a loading time of ~500ms on local but on production takes > 4s (I tested minutes ago and the loading time was 4.59s).

Why this is happening and how to solve? Can be production host hardware?

Comment: Can you check server stats? (using htop as an example). Is the problem only bandwidth related?

Comment: I'll take a look @Mtxz

Comment: As I see, likely not. Isn't pulling much server resources.

Comment: Could you try put a "large" file on the web server (100mo) and download it using your browser (not a download manager) and see speeds ?

Comment: Also, could you try installing on your server "iptraf" or "iftop" package to check network and bandwidth live usage ?

Comment: @Mtxz Downloading between 120kb/s~360kb/s. But isn't downloading more than 200kb/s in some moments.

Comment: Hum... Could you try another browser? Or a VPN? Could you try wget a "large" file from server (download it from server ssh) to see speed? What bandwidth speed does your provider " promise" ?

Comment: I don't have VPN. It's 50mb/s of download. Also, I'm in Brazil and the host are us-east1 (South Carolina) hosted in Google Cloud.

Comment: Would be great to host the site in the same country?

Comment: Ah... It's possibly because of the distances... Can you change the Google Cloud storage location ?

Comment: Yup. I'll create and move the containers to test. For now, thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Find performance issues is a massive and complex topic.  It's difficult to determine the performance issues based on small issues like you mention.  The best way is to begin with tools that will allow you to isolate your performance problems, like the [Google Chrome Audit tool](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/05/devtools-release-notes#lighthouse).

Learn how to use the tool and it will allow you to isolate the problem.  Often production servers are way over loaded, or go through periods of stress.

Comment: I'm using Audit Tool.